# Check if the device iOS version is up-to-date

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm looking for a way to check if the device is running on the most up-to-date ios version supported.
For example:
For an iPhone 7 if it's running on ios 11
And for an iPhone 5c if it's running on iOS 10.x(The max version for this device)

The solution I'm looking for is a way to check it without the need to maintain a list of the support table [Example](http://www.everyi.com/by-capability/maximum-supported-ios-version-for-ipod-iphone-ipad.html)
Is their an API that can provide this information based on the device and current version?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think so any API will provide it. You can create your own API which will fetch maximum OS compatible.

Comment: there is currently no solution in place. just one question: why would you like to identify the max OS version for a device? If you just want to identify the OS version you can also use the following code: IF #available(iOS 11.0, *) { // execute your iOS 11.0 code here } ELSE { // execute your other OS version code here }